# Cant get clicked items list from RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-recyclerview, parcelable

I'm working on a registration functionality where user can select their skill and skill level based on clicked stars. the backend json file is :

```
"candidate_skill": [
        {
            "skill_id": 1,
            "skill_level": 4
        }
    ]
```

and the design i have designed:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i need this working that user will select his skils with skill level then click on next then a list will be passed in next fragment. but currently i getting 0 size list.

Adapter Class:

```
class RegSkillAdapter(private val skills: List<String>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RegSkillAdapter.RegSkillViewholder>() {

private val selectedSkills = MutableList(skills.size) { false }
private val selectedSkillsList: ArrayList<SkillItem> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RegSkillViewholder {
    val binding =
        SkillSingleitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return RegSkillViewholder(binding)
}





override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return skills.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RegSkillViewholder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(position)
}

fun getSelectedSkillsList(): List<SkillItem> {
    return selectedSkillsList
}


inner class RegSkillViewholder(val binding: SkillSingleitemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        binding.rbSkill.setOnClickListener {
            val adapterPosition = adapterPosition
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                selectedSkills[adapterPosition] = !selectedSkills[adapterPosition]
                binding.skillstars.visibility =
                    if (selectedSkills[adapterPosition]) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

                binding.rbSkill.isChecked = selectedSkills[adapterPosition]
            }
        }

        val context = itemView.context
        val starsLayout = binding.skillstars
        val star1 = binding.star1
        val star2 = binding.star2
        val star3 = binding.star3
        val star4 = binding.star4
        val star5 = binding.star5

        star1.setOnClickListener {
            updateStars(starsLayout, 1, context)
            updateSelectedSkills(adapterPosition, 1)
        }

        star2.setOnClickListener {
            updateStars(starsLayout, 2,context)
        }

        star3.setOnClickListener {
            updateStars(starsLayout, 3,context)
        }

        star4.setOnClickListener {
            updateStars(starsLayout, 4,context)
        }

        star5.setOnClickListener {
            updateStars(starsLayout, 5,context)
        }
    }

    fun bind(position: Int) {
        binding.rbSkill.text = skills[position]
        binding.skillstars.visibility =
            if (selectedSkills[position]) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

        binding.rbSkill.isChecked = selectedSkills[position]
    }

    private fun updateStars(starsLayout: LinearLayout, selectedStars: Int, context: Context) {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            val grayStar = starsLayout.findViewById<ImageView>(
                context.resources.getIdentifier(
                    "grystar$i",
                    "id",
                    context.packageName
                )
            )
            val yellowStar = starsLayout.findViewById<ImageView>(
                context.resources.getIdentifier(
                    "ylwstar$i",
                    "id",
                    context.packageName
                )
            )

            if (i <= selectedStars) {
                yellowStar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                grayStar.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                yellowStar.visibility = View.GONE
                grayStar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateSelectedSkills(adapterPosition: Int, selectedStars: Int) {
        val skillId = adapterPosition + 1

        val skillItem = SkillItem(skillId, selectedStars)
        val existingSkillIndex = selectedSkillsList.indexOfFirst { it.skillId == skillId }

        if (existingSkillIndex != -1) {
            selectedSkillsList[existingSkillIndex] = skillItem
            Log.d("EWNARRAYRegSkillAdapter", "Updated skill: $skillItem")
        } else {
            selectedSkillsList.add(skillItem)
            Log.d("EWNARRAYRegSkillAdapter", "Added skill: $skillItem")
        }
    }}}
```

data class for list:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
```

import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class SkillItem(val skillId: Int, val skillLevel: Int):Parcelable

RegSkillFragment:

```
class RegisterSkillFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentRegisterSkillBinding
private lateinit var regSkillAdapter: RegSkillAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentRegisterSkillBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val skillList = ArrayList<String>()
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Cloud Computing")
    skillList.add("English")
    skillList.add("Art & Culture")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")
    skillList.add("Blockchain")

    regSkillAdapter = RegSkillAdapter(skillList)

    binding.rvSkill.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = regSkillAdapter
    }

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setOnclicklistener()
}

private fun setOnclicklistener() {
    binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(this)
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.btnBack -> {
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView())
                .navigate(R.id.action_registerSkillFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }

        R.id.btnNext -> {
            val selectedSkillsList = regSkillAdapter.getSelectedSkillsList()
            val parcelableList: ArrayList<SkillItem?> = ArrayList(selectedSkillsList)

            val bundle = Bundle()

            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("selectedSkillsList", parcelableList)

            Log.d("EWNARRAY", "skill list : ${parcelableList.size}")
            Log.d("EWNARRAYRegisterSkillFragment", "Selected skills list size: ${selectedSkillsList.size}")

            // Log each item individually
            for (skill in selectedSkillsList) {
                Log.d("EWNARRAY", "Skill Id: ${skill.skillId}, Skill Level: ${skill.skillLevel}")
            }
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView())
                .navigate(R.id.action_registerSkillFragment_to_registerFragment, bundle)

          /*  val registerFragment = RegisterFragment()
            registerFragment.arguments = bundle
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView())
                .navigate(R.id.action_registerSkillFragment_to_loginFragment)*/

        }
    }
}
```

}

Single Item for Rv:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding20"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding10"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbSkill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/outfit_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/RadioButtonNoBackground"
            android:textColor="@color/shark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/skillstars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/star1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:background="@drawable/lauout_bg_white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grystar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grystar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ylwstar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ylwstar"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/star2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:background="@drawable/lauout_bg_white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grystar2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grystar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ylwstar2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ylwstar"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/star3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:background="@drawable/lauout_bg_white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grystar3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grystar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ylwstar3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ylwstar"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/star4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:background="@drawable/lauout_bg_white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grystar4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grystar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ylwstar4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ylwstar"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/star5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding5"
            android:background="@drawable/lauout_bg_white"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grystar5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grystar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ylwstar5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ylwstar"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

can you see what can be the problem?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LzIE.jpg

Comment: Do you ever see the message from `Log.d("EWNARRAYRegSkillAdapter", "Added skill: $skillItem")` in the log?